# Кавычки внутри кавычек

Tags: кавычки, оформление-текста

Возможно ли внешними кавычками делать "компьютерные", а внутренними «ёлочки»? В некоторых справочниках указано, что в русском языке так не принято. Но это ведь не указание – "не принято". Где получить однозначный ответ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Жёсткого требования, полагаю, нет. Есть рекомендация.

**О кавычках внутри кавычек** ([Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/89-kav))

> Если внутри слов, заключенных в кавычки, встречаются другие слова, в свою очередь заключенные в кавычки, рекомендуется (при условии, что для этого есть технические возможности) использовать кавычки разного рисунка: внешние – «елочки», внутренние – „лапки” (или – в текстах, набранных на компьютере, – "компьютерные кавычки"). Если же такой возможности нет, то закрывающие кавычки ставятся только один раз. Кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются.
>
> **Предпочтительно:** *работа В. И. Ленина «О карикатуре на марксизм и об "империалистическом экономизме"», ЗАО «Издательский дом "Комсомольская правда"», ООО «Компания "Металлинвест"».*

Answer (score 0):

Вот что о такой, "многокавычной", ситуации говорится у А. Э. Мильчина и Л. К. Чельцовой ("Справочник издателя и автора").

**2.** Если внутри цитаты есть слова (словосочетания, фразы), в свою очередь заключенные в кавычки, то последние должны быть другого рисунка, чем кавычки, закрывающие и открывающие цитату (внешние кавычки — обычно елочки **« »**, внутренние — лапки **„ “**).

***Правильно:*** *Пушкин писал Дельвигу: «Жду „Цыганов“ и тотчас тисну».*
***Допустимо:*** *«Цыганы» мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.*

Если по техническим причинам невозможен набор кавычек другого рисунка, кавычки одного рисунка рядом не повторяются. Например, неправильно: *««Цыганы мои не продаются вовсе», — сетовал Пушкин.*
Лучше, впрочем, выделить цитаты каким-нибудь способом, сняв внешние кавычки, например, набрать цитаты со втяжкой и с абзацного отступа.

**Примечание.** Возможен набор внешних кавычек другим начертанием (например, полужирным) или внутренних кавычек — одинарными кавычками.

**3.** Если в цитате встречаются кавычки «третьей ступени», т. е. внутри заключенных в кавычки словосочетаний цитаты есть, в свою очередь, слова, взятые в кавычки, в качестве последних рекомендуются кавычки второго рисунка, т. е. лапки.

*М. М. Бахтин писал: «Тришатов рассказывает подростку о своей любви к музыке и развивает перед ним замысел оперы: „Послушайте, любите вы музыку? Я ужасно люблю... Если бы я сочинял оперу, то, знаете, я бы взял сюжет из „Фауста“. Я очень люблю эту тему“».*

[Цитаты](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html) (8.2.4. Рисунок кавычек)

Answer (score 0):

Ну это про логику записи: внешние <<кавычки>> это как скобки в уравнениях, локализующие смысловые блоки или подмножества. А "кавычки" значат оператор примененный к семантической единице или указание на семантическое восприятие слова. Поэтому внешние это скобки, а внутренние - запятые. Ну либо это попытка разбить на смысловые блоки разные фразы, фразу внутри другой фразы и тд.